# How to get i18n (internationalization) translations from user through admin panel

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am using i18n nuxt module to have two language mode in my app.

currently I have two `.js` files where translations key, value pairs are stored in them.

**Problem**

if after a while user decides that some translations need to be changed, I have to update them in the mentioned `.js` files and rebuild and deploy the app again!

**Ideal solution**

I wonder if there is a way that I can provide the user with a list of translation variables and their values in the admin panel so they can change the values through API call whenever they see fit?

any idea on how to handle this issue is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Store translations in DB

Comment: @Radeanu that is the goal, what I don't know how to implement is that how to configure `i18n nuxt module` so that it accepts translation values dynamically instead of from static files in the project? in that manner if there is another package that accepts translations dynamically, I am open to change to that package

Comment: File with messages can return either an Object or a function (supports Promises), what means you can fetch messages from DB and return the object. https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lazy-load-translations

Comment: @Radeanu thanks! it looks promising, I will check into that

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable some easy way for a non-tech savy to edit translations in your app, you can google for services like this one: https://lokalise.com/

You will be able to plug your `.js` files, the person will go to the platform, have some friendly GUI to find and edit the values that they want to edit and click on a button. This will lead to some CI, making a Pull Request to your codebase, that you can then rollout at anytime.

It is better than explaining how to edit a `.js` file in VScode and push it to a remote git branch to some non-tech person I guess.